# React+React-router on Hostinger

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I recently got the Hostinger Shared Hosting plan. However, my application is made in React and uses React-Router for routing.

However, it seems that Hostinger only accepts static hosting and client-side routing is out of the question.

How could I use client-side routing on Hostinger?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the content from the .htaccess file and it will work.

If you do not have .htaccess file in your public_html directory, just create one and paste the code below in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

This worked for me.

1. Make a file `.htaccess` in in the same directory of `index.html`
2. Run the command to build and then upload it on Hostinger.

All your routes will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter).

This uses the hash of the url to track path so it won't be considered by Hostinger's static routing.